# webpack config inside node_modules error (URL scheme "webpack" is not supported)

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-modules, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to add webpack to an npm package, the idea is that with the command "package server" I start a webpack server rendering a js file.

Basically I am making a small react clone, but I found that webpack only works if it is at the same level as the .js files and not inside node_module/package, do you have any idea how I could fix the error URL scheme "webpack" is not supported with webpack inside the node_modules folder?

```
/node_module/package/webpack.config.js

const dir = path.dirname(path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "..", ".."))); /node_module/package
console.log(path.join(dir, "src", "main.ryx"));
module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? "development" : "production",
  entry: path.join(dir, "src", "main.ryx"),
  output: {
    path: path.join(dir, ".ryunix"),

    filename: "./assets/js/[chunkhash].bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|ryx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"], (My clone does not use react, but it does use babel's react preset to compile jsx/.js.)
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg|mp4)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  ...
}
```

[webpack error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMRbI.png)

[my project structure using my npm package whith webpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSjdr.png)

Answer (score 0):

how are you? Did you notice that in the webpack error link you shared, the URL is "webpack://ryunix-vanilla/./src/main.ryx"? It's possible that the "/./" is causing the error.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. But idk how to fix it, I don't know what to change in my webpack to make it work.